# Android SurfaceView Thread with multiple activities

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I have a thread as part of a surface view object:

```
public class GameArena extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
      private GameThread thread = null;
      // Etc
}
```

And this surface view is part of an activity.

Later when the user clicks the screen, a new activity is launched, with its own different surface view.

The problem I have is finding how/when to cancel this thread when the user press' the home button in the second activity, as when they start the app again the thread already exists.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the Thread created within the SurfaceView, instead you should create the thread within an activity that owns the surfaceView. In addition, synchronization  is needed between the Thread and Activity thread the life cycle.

Comment: All of the examples I have seen on the net have the thread in the surfaceview object - is this not correct then?